# Root node problem binding DevExpress menu to a SiteMap

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I have an **ASPxMenu** bound to my *Web.sitemap* file through a standard `asp:SiteMapDataSource` control.  The menu is supposed to be horizontal, as my main top menu.  Menu and items are as follows:

```
<dx:ASPxMenu ID="topMainMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" 
    DataSourceID="siteMapDataSource" RenderMode="Lightweight">
</dx:ASPxMenu>

<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode title="" >
    <siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="Home"  description="Home page."></siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="~/Products/Main.aspx" title="Products &amp; Services"  description="Main product catalogue."></siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="~/About.aspx" title="About Us"  description="Company profile." />
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

My problem is that when the menu renders, I only get the root item, and all the items I want are in a drop down menu below that.  I don't want the root item, and I want all the other items in a horizontal menu.  In my own code for my own menus, I have a RenderRootNode flag, but that isn't an option here.

If I use a vanilla ASP.NET Menu control like this...

```
<asp:Menu ID="topMainMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" 
    DataSourceID="siteMapDataSource" StaticDisplayLevels="2">
    <LevelMenuItemStyles>
        <asp:MenuItemStyle Font-Underline="False" Width="0px" />
    </LevelMenuItemStyles>
</asp:Menu>
```

... the `StaticDisplayLevels="2"` attribute setting corrects this problem, but I can find no such setting on the **DevExpress** menu.  Maybe it's just lost among all the millions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the siteMapDataSource.ShowStartingNode property to false to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks - that SiteMapDataSource is a real stranger to me.